# PageSize of PDF always the same between landscape and portrait with itextpdf

Tags: java, pdf, itextpdf

I have a PDFReader which contains some page in landscape mode and other in portrait.

I need to distinct them to do some treatment... However, if I call the getOrientation or getPageSize, the value is always the same (595 for pagesize and 0 for orientation).

Why isn't the value different for a page in landscape ?

I've tryied to find other methods to retrieve page width / orientation but nothing worked.

Here is my code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < pdfreader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    document = PdfStamper.getOverContent(i).getPdfDocument();

    document.getPageSize().getWidth; //this will always be the same
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix :

use

```
PdfStamper.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pagenumber).getBoundingBox().getWidth()
```

instead of

```
stamper.getOverContent(i).getPdfDocument().getPageSize().getWidth();
```

Comment: That's a strange fix. Please take a look at my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

There are two convenience methods, named `getPageSize()` and `getPageSizeWithRotation()`.

Let's take a look at an example:

```
PdfReader reader =
    new PdfReader("src/main/resources/pages.pdf");
show(reader.getPageSize(1));
show(reader.getPageSize(3));
show(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(3));
show(reader.getPageSize(4));
show(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(4));
```

In this example, the `show()` method looks like this:

```
public static void show(Rectangle rect) {
    System.out.print("llx: ");
    System.out.print(rect.getLeft());
    System.out.print(", lly: ");
    System.out.print(rect.getBottom());
    System.out.print(", urx: ");
    System.out.print(rect.getRight());
    System.out.print(", lly: ");
    System.out.print(rect.getTop());
    System.out.print(", rotation: ");
   System.out.println(rect.getRotation());
}
```

This is the output:

```
llx: 0.0, lly: 0.0, urx: 595.0, lly: 842.0, rotation: 0
llx: 0.0, lly: 0.0, urx: 595.0, lly: 842.0, rotation: 0
llx: 0.0, lly: 0.0, urx: 842.0, lly: 595.0, rotation: 90
llx: 0.0, lly: 0.0, urx: 842.0, lly: 595.0, rotation: 0
llx: 0.0, lly: 0.0, urx: 842.0, lly: 595.0, rotation: 0
```

Page 3 (see line 4 in code sample 3.8) is an A4 page just like page 1, but it's oriented in landscape. The `/MediaBox` entry is identical to the one used for the first page `[0 0 595 842]`, and that's why `getPageSize()` returns the same result.

The page is in landscape, because the `\Rotate` entry in the page dictionary is set to `90`. Possible values for this entry are `0` (which is the default value if the entry is missing), `90`, `180` and `270`.

The `getPageSizeWithRotation()` method takes this value into account. It swaps the width and the height so that you're aware of the difference. It also gives you the value of the `/Rotate` entry.

Page 4 also has a landscape orientation, but in this case, the rotation is mimicked by adapting the `/MediaBox` entry. In this case the value of the `/MediaBox` is `[0 0 842 595]` and if there's a `/Rotate` entry, its value is `0`.

That explains why the output of the `getPageSizeWithRotation()` method is identical to the output of the `getPageSize()` method.

When I read your question, I see that you are looking for the rotation. This can be done with the `getRotation()` method.

**Remark:** This text is copied from my book ["The ABC of PDF"](http://itextpdf.com/learn) (the book is under construction; you can download the first chapters for free). The code sample can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/pdfabc/chapter03/C0305_PageBoundaries).