# Itext get cropped page orientation

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to create app which crops pdf and rotates pages ( all pages should have longer side horizontal).

I first use this function to crop:

```
public void obreziPDF(string fileName)
{
     f (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
     {
        string putanja = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
        for (int p = 1; p <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; p++)
        {
            PdfDictionary page = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
            Rectangle rect = getOutputPageSize(pdfReader, 1);
            float[] flo = { rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Right, rect.Top };
            PdfArray pdfa = new PdfArray(flo);
            page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, pdfa);
            stamper.MarkUsed(page);
        }
        stamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
     }
}
```

and this to check rotation and rotate if needed.

```
public void okreniPDF(string fileName)
{
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                string putanja = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
                PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
                // PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);
                PdfStamper stamper1 = new PdfStamper(pdfReader1, new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
                for (int p = 1; p <= pdfReader1.NumberOfPages; p++)
                {
                    Rectangle mediabox = pdfReader1.GetPageSize(1);
                    Rectangle cropbox = pdfReader1.GetCropBox(1);
                    Rectangle r1 = pdfReader1.GetBoxSize(1, "media");
                    PdfDictionary page1 = pdfReader1.GetPageN(1);
                    Rectangle pagesize = pdfReader1.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page1);
                    if (arotiraj.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        if (pagesize.Left - pagesize.Right > 300)
                        {
                            if (pagesize.Left - pagesize.Right < pagesize.Top - pagesize.Bottom)
                            {
                                page1.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
                            }
                        }
                    }
       }
                stamper1.Close();
       pdfReader1.Close();
    }
}
```

Problem is that Rectangle pagesize get uncropped size. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following FAQ topics:

- [How can I crop the pages of an existing PDF document?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-crop-pages-existing-pdf-document)
- [How to get the page width and height of a PDF document?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-pdf-page-width-and-height)

When I read the subject of your question, I assumed that you were defining a crop box. When I read your code, I see that you don't change anything.

You create a loop that is supposed to visit every page, but you always get the page dictionary of the first page.

You have:

```
PdfDictionary page = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
```

But I would expect:

```
PdfDictionary page = pdfReader.GetPageN(p);
```

I don't know what the `getOutputPageSize()` method is about, but you also pass `1` as a parameter where I would expect p`. That doesn't seem right.

You are making the same mistake in the `okreniPDF()` method. You try to change the first page *and the first page only* as many times as there are pages in the document. That is highly ineffective.

**Update:**

Apparently you knew about your mistake, and you now claim that the problem you are experiencing is a different one. However, you don't explain the nature of your problem. Maybe your interpretation of what you are seeing is all wrong.

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356772/1622493 for more info.

Comment: Bruno thanks for answer. I now about loop mistake it was made attencionaly for testing  purposes. obreziPDF() does its job and crops pages (As in acrobat remove white margins) - I saw it in acrobat reader. But when okreniPDF()  asks for dimensions it only gets original dimensions not ones that obreziPDF() croped.

Comment: Please clean up your question. The error you made with the pages in the loop, was a certain mistake, and you should have expected that as the first answer. You also have variables such as `mediabox` and `cropbox`that are never used in `okreniPDF()`. Also: how do you know that the original dimensions are fetched? You never check them. I think your problem lies in the sloppiness of your code. Clean it up and improve your question: *why do you think the wrong dimensions are retrieved?* That's not clear from your question.

Comment: I think that your interpretation of what is returned by the get page size methods is wrong. Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/23356772/1622493

Comment: I clean my code and I am getting same results. 
Orginal size of document is: 841x1189.
My question is when I use obreziPDF() on PDF file. Size  in adobe reader is 336 x 476. When I use code to get size after obreziPDF() using your example I always get original size.
How I get by code size 336 x 476?

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the original document instead of to the new document. Have you opened the document with iText RUPS? What do you see when you look at the page boundaries? Note that Adobe Reader give you the dimensions of the Crop Box, whereas `getPageSize()` gives you the dimensions of the Media Box.