# Adding text top-right of PDF using ColumnText works for Portrait, not for Landscape

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working on a project where as part of statements I need to attach arbitrary PDF files. These PDF files need to be marked by a title and page numbering, in the top-right corner of the PDF file. This is a legal requirement as these attachments are referred to by their title and total number of pages from the statements.

I (naively) hacked together some code that appears to be working on PDF files with pages in the Portrait orientation (at least the PDF files I tested with). However when I use this code on pages in a Landscape orientation, the title and numbering isn't visible.

---

**The code:**

```
PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getOverContent( pageNr );

Phrase phrase = new Phrase( sb.toString( ), new Font( FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9f ) ); // sb holds title + page numbering
float width = ColumnText.getWidth( phrase );

ColumnText.showTextAligned ( // draw text top-right
    canvas,
    Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
    phrase,
    canvas.getPdfDocument( ).right( ) - width, //x
    canvas.getPdfDocument( ).top( ) + 9, //y
    0 //rotation
);
```

---

**Examples:**

- Portrait where it appears to work:

[image]

- Landscape where it doesn't work:

[image]

---

**Questions:**

- Where did I go wrong?
- Is it possible to write such a piece of code that does it right for all possible page orientations?
- If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the content, but you are adding it at the wrong place. See [PageSize of PDF always the same between landscape and portrait with itextpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353146/pagesize-of-pdf-always-the-same-between-landscape-and-portrait-with-itextpdf)

Let's assume that you are working with an A4 page using portrait orientation. That pages measures 595 by 842 user units. 595 is the width; 842 is the height.

Now let's switch to landscape. This can be done in two different ways:

1. define a width of 595 and a height of 842, and a rotation of 90 degrees.
2. define a width of 842 and a height of 595.

Which way is used to define the landscape orientation will have an impact on the value of the `right()` and `top()` method. I am pretty sure that you are adding the header to the landscape pages, but you are adding them *outside the visible area of the page*.

Comment: Thank you for your insights Bruno. I solved the issue by using `pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation( pageNr )` as the basis to place the title/numbering.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I ended up doing it as follows. This works for both Portrait and Landscape orientations. This uses the [`PdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getPageSizeWithRotation-int-) method to get the proper page size.

---

```
private String pageText(int pageNr, int pageTotal) {
    return ""; // generate string to display top-right of PDF here
}

private void addDocumentObjects(int pageNr, PdfReader pdfReader, PdfStamper pdfStamper) {
    final float pageMargin = 25f;
    final float textSize = 9f;
    final float lineMargin = 5f;

    Phrase phrase = new Phrase (
        pageText(pageNr, pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()),
        new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, textSize)
    );
    final float phraseWidth = ColumnText.getWidth(phrase);

    PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getOverContent(pageNr);
    com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageNr);

    // draw white background rectangle before adding text + line
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
    canvas.rectangle (
        pageRectangle.getRight(pageMargin) - phraseWidth, //x
        pageRectangle.getTop(pageMargin), //y
        phraseWidth, // width
        textSize + lineMargin //height
    );
    canvas.fill();

    // draw text top right
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned (
        canvas, //canvas
        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, //alignment
        phrase, //phrase
        pageRectangle.getRight(pageMargin) - phraseWidth, //x 
        pageRectangle.getTop(pageMargin), //y
        0 //rotation
    );

    // draw line under text
    canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
    canvas.setLineWidth(1);
    canvas.moveTo (
        pageRectangle.getRight(pageMargin) - phraseWidth, //x
        pageRectangle.getTop(pageMargin) - lineMargin //y
    );
    canvas.lineTo (
        pageRectangle.getRight(pageMargin), //x
        pageRectangle.getTop(pageMargin) - lineMargin //y
    );
    canvas.stroke();
}
```